# ResultSet into a Popup List

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, jdbc, resultset

So I have this and would like to know if there is a way to store each hospital that is found into an array, which is then put into a pop-up box that the user can select a hospital from and store that as a choice to be past to a different class later on

```
while(results.next())               
            {
                // Put into interactive list
                String hospital = results.getString("hospitalName");

                // Loops each hospital via popup, needs to be added to a selection menu
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, hospital, "Hospital List", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Does the option pane expect a collection?

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate things.

You should *never* mingle database and UI code together.  Once you do that, you can never reuse that database code without the UI.

Keep them separate. Get the query right, then worry about how to add it to a popup.

The pop up answer depends a great deal on how you're doing the user interface.  I'd give a different answer if it's desktop (Swing) or web ( server side, like Spring MVC, or client side, like angular).

One good option for all is to write a REST server that exposes the list as JSON.  You can reuse that all day long.

Comment: Well to answer the question I'm usinf Jframes/Swing but I see

Comment: It's a common mistake to embed all your code in Swing listeners.  I would advise you to start with interface based POJOs for database code.  Get those working and tested; inject them into your Swing UI and let it call the classes to interact with the database.

Comment: EDIT: I'll make a new question.